# Why does changing the highlighted button in my "button grid" for my calculator cause the previously highlighted button text to disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm building a tip calculator that has a grid of buttons for possible percentages. When any tip button is selected, I want the font and background color to change. Here's my issue, if I have a tip button selected, and then change the focus to a different tip button, the text on the previously focused tip button disappears? And then if you hover over it, it re-appears.

I have a class in CSS for the font color of any unselected button. On the click event, I tried looping over each button in the grid and manually adding that font using the DOM, but I still get this "disappearing text" issue. Do I need to be doing something with the 'blur' event? I'm stuck! Here's my code for this button grid:

```
tipTiles.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    tipTiles.forEach((tile) => {
      if (tile.classList.contains("btn-bg2")) {
        tile.classList.remove("btn-bg2");
        tile.classList.remove("btn-font2");
        tile.classList.add("btn-font1");
      }

      e.currentTarget.classList.add("btn-bg2");
      e.currentTarget.classList.add("btn-font2");
    });
  });
});
```

Link to the project below:

https://tips-calculation.netlify.app/#

Comment: All you're doing here is adding and removing class-names; without the HTML and - importantly - the CSS there's nothing we can really do. Please, read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, and also see "*[ask]*"

Comment: I just tried replicating your issues but it seems to be working fine for me. I have text and background color changing when I click and hover over any other button. I am using Safari 15.3. What browser are you using? Is it in development mode? That can cause issues with events behaving properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it must fix your problem:)

1. Remove btn-bg1 btn-font1 classes from your elments in Html, like this:

> ```
> <li class="tip-tile" tabindex="0">
> ```

2. In style.css find .tip-tile:last-child and add color: unset; after that it should look like this:

> ```
> .tip-tile:last-child {
>   color: unset;
>   text-align: center;
>   padding: 0.5rem;
>   border-radius: 5px;
>   font-size: 1.2rem;
>   background-color: #f4fafa;
>   -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
>   transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
> }
> ```

3. Update your js code with this one:

> ```
> tipTiles.forEach((el) => {
>   tipTiles.forEach((tile) => {
>     tile.classList.remove("tip-tile");
>     tile.classList.add('btn-bg1', 'btn-font1', 'tip-tile');
>   });
>   el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
>     tipTiles.forEach((tile) => {
>       if (tile.classList.contains('btn-bg2')) {
>         tile.classList.remove("tip-tile");
>         tile.classList.replace("btn-bg2", "btn-bg1");
>         tile.classList.replace("btn-font2", "btn-font1");
>         tile.classList.add("tip-tile");
>       }
>       e.currentTarget.classList.replace("btn-bg1", "btn-bg2");
>       e.currentTarget.classList.replace("btn-font1", "btn-font2");
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```

> ```
> resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
>   if (totalAmount.textContent !== 0) {
>     totalAmount.textContent = "$0.00";
>     tipAmount.textContent = "$0.00";
>     billField.value = 0;
>     peopleField.value = 0;
>     resetBtn.classList.remove("btn-bg2");
>
>     tipTiles.forEach((tile) => {
>       if (tile.classList.contains("btn-bg2")) {
>         tile.classList.remove("tip-tile");
>         tile.classList.replace("btn-bg2", "btn-bg1");
>         tile.classList.replace("btn-font2", "btn-font1");
>         tile.classList.add("tip-tile");
>       }
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: You earned the gold! You fixed my problem, thank you!